# Convert facebook date format to javascript date

Tags: javascript, date, facebook-fql

Hi i'm getting events from facebook with fql and javascript sdk.

How can i convert the facebook format date in a javascript date?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

for changing the graph api "created_time" into a "ago" date to match facebook I found the fallowing link for javascript / jquery useful : http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/

```
var created_time = "2012-04-10T00:17:46+0000";
alert(timeAgo(created_time));

function timeAgo(time){
var date = new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," ")),
    diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000),
    day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);

if ( isNaN(day_diff) || day_diff < 0 || day_diff >= 31 )
    return;

return day_diff == 0 && (
        diff < 60 && "just now" ||
        diff < 120 && "1 minute ago" ||
        diff < 3600 && Math.floor( diff / 60 ) + " minutes ago" ||
        diff < 7200 && "1 hour ago" ||
        diff < 86400 && Math.floor( diff / 3600 ) + " hours ago") ||
    day_diff == 1 && "Yesterday" ||
    day_diff < 7 && day_diff + " days ago" ||
    day_diff < 31 && Math.ceil( day_diff / 7 ) + " weeks ago";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for how to convert the graph api "created_time" to timestamp.

Comment: @JoeHuang :  Your solution is working nicely on Chrome + Safari, but not Firefox. Do you know why ?

Comment: @ihue Take a closer look, it's not my solution :) I only test it with node.js, I am not using browsers. You maybe want to ask your question as a separate question in SO to describe "not Firefox" in details.

Answer (score 6):

Dates in javascript are numeric values of milliseconds since January 1, 1970.  Facebook dates (at least creation_time and update_time in the stream table) are in seconds since January 1, 1970 so you need to multiply by 1000.  Here is some code doing it for a post on my wall earlier today ([*fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/Qjk4V/)):

```
var created_time = 1276808857;
var created_date = new Date(created_time * 1000);
var current_date = new Date();
console.log('Post: ' + moment(created_date).format())
console.log('Now: ' + moment(current_date).format());
```

Result:

```
Post: 2010-06-17T16:07:37-05:00
Now: 2013-11-12T16:37:01-06:00
```

I used the code here to format the dates:
http://momentjs.com/

Comment: The link provided here is dead.

Comment: Updated to use momentjs and added a fiddle

Answer (score 2):

According to what I read [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:date) concerning the fql date format, you can get it in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format (long_numeric).

I am guessing that you could use a regular expression or the following in Javascript.

```
var dateString = 'mm/dd/yyyy' //where 'mm/dd/yyyy' is the facebook format date

var myDate = new Date(dateString);
document.write("Date :" + myDate.getDate());
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Month : " + myDate.getMonth());
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Year : " + myDate.getFullYear());
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook date format defaults to "2000-01-01T00:00:59+0000", but if you specify `date_format=U` in the query, then the format is the unix timestamp integer (e.g. 1428093522).

Then, get the Javascript time simply with `new Date(unix_timestamp*1000)`;

Answer (score 0):

**add jquery ui plugin in your page.**

```
function DateFormate(dateFormate, dateTime) {
    return $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormate, dateTime);
};
```